# Add programmatically clickable Button with custom Views layouted in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView. 
In there I add buttons programmatically. 
Right now I just use UIButton and set one title. But I need to have an UIImage View in there, that will change upon certain events, Text that will change too etc. and I would like to style that in Interface Builder, but I can't figure out how to do this. Which class should I extend, and what kind of xib should I create and what in there, so that in the end I can make the right connections and so that I can listen for UIControlEventTouchDown of that Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a UIViewController subclass with a nib.  You can do everything you want from there.

Comment: thx, it worked. It wasn't what I wanted, but I guess only thing that matters is that it works. Only thing was, I didn't have a touchupinside in the uiviewcontroller, but I wrote my own touchupinside by using touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded.